# Devexpress Form With Header Panel (Title) and Menu Below Panel

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

Can someone give me insight how can I achieve the form with panel title first and then menu bar below panel (barmanager). Because devexpress always put barmanager on top

[image]

Thank you

EDIT :

After I add standalonebardock, the result as picture shown below: the red bar is standalonebardock

[image]

UPDATE :

After I drag the barmanager menu into standalonedock, now it is already inside the dock. But the menu still on top docking, what I need how to make space above menu so I can write title/image/etc

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [StandaloneBarDockControl](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.StandaloneBarDockControl) control allows bars to be displayed at any position within the form, not simply docked to the form’s edge. To do this, create a StandaloneBarDockControl object and add bars to it. Bars can be added to the control at design time or runtime.

Comment: thank you for your reply..how ever i still not able to get what i expected. you can see the picture after I add standalonebardock..the red one is below the barmanager menu

Comment: Just move your bars into the StandaloneBarDockControl and then place it(StandaloneBarDockControl) into the layout where is required. Honestly, it is not quite clear to me what problem you fall into with this...